# Self sign certificate programatically

Tags: c++, linux, openssl

I'm trying to build a fake HTTPS server (like mitmproxy), so I made an SSL "sign" function. after generating and installing the certificate on my system I got the error: "NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID"/ "MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_SELF_SIGNED_CERT".

The code looks like

```
    static bool generateX509(const std::shared_ptr<CA>& ca, SSL *ssl, const char * domain)
    {
        auto ca_cert = ca->ca_crt.get();
        auto ca_pkey = ca->ca_key.get();

        // --- cert generation ---
        std::unique_ptr<X509, void (*)(X509 *)> cert { X509_new(), X509_free };
        
        X509_set_notBefore(cert.get(), X509_get_notBefore(ca_cert));
        X509_set_notAfter(cert.get(), X509_get_notAfter(ca_cert));
        
        X509_set_serialNumber(cert.get(), X509_get_serialNumber(ca_cert));
        
        X509_set_pubkey(cert.get(), X509_get_pubkey(ca_cert));
        
        X509_set_version(cert.get(), 2);
        
        const unsigned char country[] = "RU";
        const unsigned char company[] = "MyCompany, PLC";
        
        X509_name_st* name = X509_get_subject_name(cert.get());
        X509_NAME_add_entry_by_txt(name, "C",  MBSTRING_ASC, country, -1, -1, 0);
        X509_NAME_add_entry_by_txt(name, "O",  MBSTRING_ASC, company, -1, -1, 0);
        X509_NAME_add_entry_by_txt(name, "CN", MBSTRING_ASC, (const unsigned char *)domain, -1, -1, 0);
        
        X509_set_issuer_name(cert.get(), name);
        
        X509_EXTENSION *Extension;
        char Buffer[512];
        
        // Format the value
        sprintf (Buffer, "DNS:%s", domain);
        Extension = X509V3_EXT_conf_nid (nullptr, nullptr, NID_subject_alt_name, Buffer);
        if (Extension) {
            X509_add_ext (cert.get(), Extension, -1);
            X509_EXTENSION_free (Extension);
        }
        
        X509_sign(cert.get(), ca_pkey, EVP_sha256()); // some hash type here
        
        SSL_use_certificate(ssl, cert.get());
        SSL_use_PrivateKey(ssl, ca_pkey);
        
        return true;

    }
```

What i missing?

How to resolve this error

Comment: Do not tag C for questions that do not involve C.

Comment: Digital signing is designed to prevent the kind of thing you are trying to do. You cannot impersonate another certificate authority.